# Target an element inside the parent div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, parent, slidetoggle

I use this code to show and hide the div with a class named "text":

```
$(".text").hide();
$('.more-link').click(function(){
       $(".text").slideToggle();         
 });
```

Together with this HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <div class="text">
        <p>Even more text</p>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="more-link">Read more</a>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <div class="text">
        <p>Even more text</p>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="more-link">Read more</a>
</div>
```

I need help to target the specific "div.text" in the parent div. I guess I should use the parent() function, but I don't understand how I should apply it.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What element is being used to drive this process? That will determine how you navigate to the appropriate element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do (in this way each links shows only the relative text):

```
$(".text").hide();
$('.more-link').click(function(){
       $(this).prev(".text").slideToggle();         
 });
```

fidlle: http://jsfiddle.net/QEVXf/

Comment: This is the best solution so far. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.text').hide();
$('.more-link').click(function(){
   $(this).parent().find('.text').slideToggle();         
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$('.more-link').click(function(){
       $(".text").slideToggle();         
});
```

with

```
$('.more-link').click(function(){
       $(this).parent().find(".text").slideToggle();         
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$(".text").hide();
$('.more-link').click(function(e){
    $(this).parent().find(".text").slideToggle();         
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".text").hide();
$('.more-link').click(function(){
       $(this).siblings(".text").slideToggle();         
 });
```